# How to make R stop reading rows in a text file at a line containing a specific character?

Tags: r, text-mining

For example, I want to read lines from the beginning of a text file up to a string with `";"` symbol excluding this string.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach might be to read the contents of the using `readLines`:

```
content = readLines("data.txt")
```

And then split the character data on the `;`:

```
split_content = strsplit(content, split = ";")
```

And then extract the first elememt, i.e. the text up to the semicolon:

```
first_element = lapply(split_content, "[[", 1]
```

The result is a list of all the text in the rows of the data file up to the semicolon.

Ps I'm not entirely sure about the last line...I can't check it as I've got no access to R right now.